# Getting IOException in bluetooth Application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to learn Bluetooth connection between a Server and a Client app. All worked well and my app run for the first time but after that suddenly I got an

> IOException :"Not able to register SDP record for NAME

and now it gets this Exception every time i try to run the application 
I am getting the Exception here :

```
try {

    tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
    NAME, MY_UUID); // this line is throwing the exception
} catch (IOException e) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

I have searched about the error but i didn't find anything of much help .
Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11683410/92837

Comment: @sathya the link was really helpful thank you very much :)

Comment: @sathya you have already given me the link. Thank you :)